How to adjust the spacing between radio buttons and 'WizardForm.DirEdit' box?
A little while ago I asked the question:
"How can I create separate install paths for Steam & Epic Games, selected by radio buttons, or a pathbox for custom install?", to which I got a great response by Martin Prikryl. Unfortunately though I ran into a little pickle due to my lack of clarifying what exactly I had planned UX-wise. I tried fixing it, but I just couldn't understand this tiny little section of his [Code] that controlled the creation of the buttons.

The section from Martin's [Code] :

var
  SteamButton: TNewRadioButton;
  EpicButton: TNewRadioButton;
  CustomButton: TNewRadioButton;

function CreateButton(var Top: Integer): TNewRadioButton;
begin
  Result := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  Result.Parent := WizardForm.DirEdit.Parent;
  Result.Top := Top;
  Result.Left := WizardForm.SelectDirBrowseLabel.Left;
  Result.Width := Result.Parent.ClientWidth - Result.Left;
  Result.OnClick := @DirButtonClick;
  Top := Result.Top + Result.Height + ScaleY(24); 
end;

Can anyone explain how to separate the buttons, but not the path box?


Example of what was deisred shown here:



If you need different spacing after every radio button, move the spacing code out of the shared CreateButton implementation:
SteamButton := CreateButton();
SteamButton.Caption := '&Steam';
SteamButton.Enabled := DirExists(SteamDirName);
SteamButton.Top := WizardForm.SelectDirBrowseLabel.Top;

EpicButton := CreateButton();
EpicButton.Caption := '&Epic Games';
EpicButton.Enabled := DirExists(EpicDirName);
EpicButton.Top := SteamButton.Top + SteamButton.Height + ScaleY(24);

CustomButton := CreateButton();
CustomButton.Caption := '&Custom path:';
CustomButton.Top := EpicButton.Top + EpicButton.Height + ScaleY(24);

Top := CustomButton.Top + CustomButton.Height + ScaleY(8);
WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Top :=
  WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Top + (Top - WizardForm.DirEdit.Top);
 WizardForm.DirEdit.Top := Top;

And of course, remove all references to Top from CreateButton.


Another (easier-to-do) option is to make the ScaleY parameter be a parameter of the CreateButton function.

Thanks for the response and sorry if it was a dumb question. I just really was having trouble understanding what was going on, didn't even think about the function being the problem. Also, out of complete curiosity; what VCL style are you using?

Np. I'm not using VCL styles. This is the default Windows 11 style.
